# vi/vim: how to scroll by a third of window height

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

As I understand it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> scroll the window by the number of lines that is set in the `scroll` option, which defaults to half of the height of the window. Can it be changed to scroll by a third of the window height?

Comment: Ooh, getting this to happen in less too would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following ex command. It uses the variable `lines` that show how many lines are shown in a window and calculates the third.

```
:execute "set scroll=" .&lines / 3
```

**EDIT**: When window is resized the scroll value won't change, so add following autocommand to your `vimrc` to fix it:

```
:au VimResized * execute "set scroll=" . &lines / 3
```

Comment: @Alexander, `&lines` is the height of Vim as a whole, not the height of the current window. Use `winheight('.')` to get the height of the current window.

Comment: It's required to handle more events to cover all cases of window resizing.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76897505/22330192) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The default value of `scroll` is dynamic — could be `12` in one window and `21` in another one — but the proportion, `50%`, is hardcoded. AFAIK, that proportion used to calculate `scroll` dynamically can't be modified.

You can change the value of `scroll` pretty easily with something like this:

```
execute "set scroll=" . winheight('.') / 3
```

Now you must find how, when and where to use that snippet. An `autocmd` seems to be a good choice choice but what event shall we use? `WinEnter`/`WinLeave`? `CursorMove`? Something else?

Maybe a simple mapping that overrides the default? Something like:

```
nnoremap <C-d> :execute "normal! " . winheight('.') / 3 . "^D"<CR>
" type <C-v> then <C-d> to produce ^D
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent command to scroll up? `^U` doesn't work, it produces a `:"` in my command line

Comment: I have the same issue: `^U` doesn't work, it produces a `:"` in my command line

Comment: I've adopted this into NeoVim's Lua API like so: ```vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<C-d>', vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes([[(winheight(0)/3).'<C-d>']], true, false, false), {noremap = true, expr = true, desc = 'jump-down a third of the window-height'})```
https://github.com/alxndr/dotfiles/blob/1e15f771a9/nvim/lua/mappings.lua#L80

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have the `scroll` value set to one third of the window height in your `~/.vimrc`.  Though, the trouble with doing that using `set scroll=<value>` is that the `scroll` value becomes reset to `0`, i.e. to the default of half the window height, whenever the current window size changes. For example, that happens when accessing the built-in help using `:h <topic>`, or when browsing the search history using `q/`.  See `:h scroll` for more details.

To preserve the `scroll` setting across all windows and after all window size changes, you can add this vimscript code to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set scroll=float2nr(winheight('.') / 3)

function! PreserveScroll(timer)
  set scroll=float2nr(winheight('.') / 3)
endfunction

augroup vimrc-preserve-scroll
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimResized * set scroll=float2nr(winheight('.') / 3)
  autocmd WinEnter   * set scroll=float2nr(winheight('.') / 3)
  autocmd WinLeave   * call timer_start(300, "PreserveScroll", {"repeat": 3})
augroup END
```

Obviously, setting up a timer isn't the best solution, but unfortunately I see no better way to have the desired `set scroll=<value>` executed upon returning to a window, for example after closing the help window.

---

Here's a slightly improved version of the same vimscript code, in the sense of keeping the calculation and assignment of the `scroll` value in a single place:

```
function! PreserveScroll(timer = v:null)
  set scroll=float2nr(winheight('.') / 3)
endfunction

augroup vimrc-preserve-scroll
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimResized * call PreserveScroll() 
  autocmd WinEnter   * call PreserveScroll()
  autocmd WinLeave   * call timer_start(300, "PreserveScroll", {"repeat": 3})
augroup END

call PreserveScroll()
```

This version of the code is perhaps a tiny, *tiny* bit less efficient than the original version, because it inevitably consumes a few extra CPU cycles, but that's a totally acceptable trade-off for having no duplicated code.

I use this improved version of the vimscript code in my `~/.vimrc`, but modified to set the `scroll` value to `1`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76897135/22330192) for more details.