# How to scroll (move screen up/down while cursor remains fixed at same screen position) in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

When scrolling normally on a webpage, the cursor remains at the same place on the screen while the screen shifts smoothly up/down. I would like to replicate that functionality in vim. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> move the screen but the cursor does not stay at the same position on screen, it stays on same row.

So far, the only thing that comes close is  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, but this scrolls half the screen's worth in rows. This doesn't enable smooth scrolling.

Is there a built-in command for that?

Comment: you can map your own, such as `nnoremap <C-E> <C-E>k` which will make `ctrl-e` do both motions together.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Currently it looks like you want us to write the script or to find it for you, either of which is off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43888638/128421.

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. I do want to move both the screen AND the cursor one line up/down. That question states how to move screen WITHOUT moving cursor.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I figured out the correct mappings. If the screen goes down one line the cursor should go up by one line and vice versa (instead of both screen and cursor going up one/down one line). This is to create the desired "scrolling" effect. The bindings I have made and tested to work are `nnoremap <C-K> k<C-Y>` and `nnoremap <C-J> j<C-E>`. `<C-K>` and `<C-J>` are [unused bindings](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Unused_keys) by default in vim which is convenient since they now simulate a similar effect to `j` and `k` and allows me to keep the default functionality of `<C-E>` and `<C-Y>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no default way to do it, I opted to use

`nnoremap <C-K> k<C-Y>`

and

`nnoremap <C-J> j<C-E>`

Answer (score 1):

The `'scroll'` option determines the number of lines <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> scroll. The default of `0` is "half a screen"; but if you

```
:set scr=1
```

then those commands will only move you by one line. (You can get back to the default using `:set scr=0`.)

Note that `'scroll'` option is automatically set by prefixing <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> with a count. I.e. if you do <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, every further <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> will only move by one line until `'scroll'` is reset.

Another possibility is `'scrolloff'`, which determines the minimum number of lines above and below the cursor in a window. Setting it to a ridiculous number will make sure your cursor is always in the centre of the screen. That is,

```
:set so=999
```

will de facto convert `j` and `k` into what you desired.

Finally, a binding like Christian Gibbons suggests in comments is another way to do this, if you dislike the side effects of these two methods.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I dislike the side effects so I used slightly modified bindings than the ones Christian Gibbons suggested. The ones he suggests don't create the desired "scrolling" effect. The bindings I used are `nnoremap <C-K> k<C-Y>` and `nnoremap <C-J> j<C-E>`

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76897135/22330192) for more vimscript code that's required to handle the `set scroll=1` setting properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `set scroll=1` to your `~/.vimrc`, and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to scroll the window up and down, respectively.

Though, the trouble with using `set scroll=1` is that the `scroll` value becomes reset back to the default of half the window height whenever the current window size changes.  For example, that happens when the built-in help is opened using `:h scroll`, or when the search history is browsed using `q/`.

To preserve the `scroll` setting across all windows and after all window size changes, I've added this vimscript code to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set scroll=1

function! PreserveScroll(timer)
  set scroll=1
endfunction

augroup vimrc-preserve-scroll
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimResized * set scroll=1
  autocmd WinEnter   * set scroll=1
  autocmd WinLeave   * call timer_start(300, "PreserveScroll", {"repeat": 3})
augroup END
```

Obviously, setting up a timer isn't the best solution, but unfortunately I see no better way to have `set scroll=1` executed upon returning to a window, for example after closing the help window.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16574404/22330192) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76897505/22330192) for another variant of this approach.